Mobile pre-loader not centered
I am facing issue understanding how mobile pre-loader works. So I have a pre-loader which is centered perfectly fine vertically and horizontally on the Desktop screen. I can open up dev tools and see the same on all layouts, it is perfectly centered and responsive.
Now the issue happens on my own phone. If I hit the URL (My IP + port), the page loads and the pre-loader/text is not centered vertically but a bit to the bottom. If I touch the screen and interact with it, then suddenly it comes into the center. If I refresh the page, then on first load it is centered. The issue only happens when I hit the URL for the first time even a simple text won't be centered no matter what style I apply.
It leads me to believe that I lack information on how mobile browser layout works and need some help understanding it.
I thought it might be an issue with my project, but I created a fresh Next.js project.
This is my root page.js:
import Loading from ./components/Loading;
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Loading />
  );
}

And this is my Loading component:
import styles from "./Loading.module.css";

const Loading = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.landingLoadingDiv}>
      <p className={styles.loadingText}>NextJS</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Loading;

Loading.module.css:
.landingLoadingDiv {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .loadingText {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0;
  }

I know styling is not an issue, this is something that I don't understand with how mobile rendering is working.
Here is what it visually looks like:


You need to understand that on mobile devices, we have dynamic viewport size. Try scrolling up and down, and you will see that the webpage view expands or contracts when the controls of the mobile browser starts to hide/reveal.
You can read more about dvh here.

Hmm yep this is the behaviour I described in my explanation. If I scroll up and down it suddenly centers. If I reload the page then also it is vertically centered. Only on first hit of the url it causes this issue. I tried adding 100dvh; but I am still seeing no difference.

You can try lvh. This will be a bit of batter.

It didn't work. I tried 100svh as well but the text always seems to come to bottom. I wouldn't mind that in a normal website but this website I am building needs to have pre-loader and it wouldn't look nice.
